# Ubuntu on Macbook Mid 2009 network not working

Tags: drivers, macbook

I've just finished my install of Ubuntu, but have no drivers what so ever. 
When I try to hook it to the internet by cable it keeps disconnecting, and wireless is no option.

How can I get my internet (and everything else) working properly?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if this would help or not but maybe it's a bad install, or you could try buying a usb wifi adapter that works with linux.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook

If you can give us the model info, it will help a lot. You can get it by writing this command to your terminal:

```
    sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
```

It should print out something like this: "MacBook5,5". You can find the terminal by going to Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal.

If you are lucky, you may find the answer from the above link using the model name found by using the above command.